# Intel Xeon Phi and ANSYS FLUENT

Tags: intel, fluent, hardware-acceleration, xeon-phi

Has anyone turned effectively accelerate calculations in ANSYS FLUENT (into ANSYS Workbench 14-15-16 versions) via Intel Xeon Phi: 5110P or 31S1P model?

It is possible? Does FLUENT support these co-proccessors?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question best asked of Ansys. Looking at their web site, it appears not yet.